# Should Event Scheduled Reminders be sent if they were due to go out before a person registers

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

Scenario:

There is a Scheduled Reminder due to go out 10 days and 3 days prior to an Event.

A person registers for the Event 2 days prior to it.

Does CiviCRM send the 10 day prior and the 3 day prior Reminders?

I am asking as a client on a customised (by others) CiviCRM 4.4.x is complaining that these Reminders are being sent out, but they should not.

Hoping that users with 4.6.x or 4.7.x can answer this, otherwise I will set up some tests to confirm.

NOTE: these are Scheduled Reminders that were set up via the tab on the Event config screen not via the Communications > Scheduled Reminders but assume that should make no difference

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that yes, the reminders do go out in the scenario you described.  I wish there was a way to turn them off in this scenario but I have not found one.

Comment: I can confirm that this is still the case in 4.7.17.

Answer (score 0):

I thought CiviCRM had a 24hr window when considering whether to send or not. So in your example I would expect the registrant to get the 3 day prior reminder but not the 10 day one as its more than 24hrs outside of the rule. Things might have changed but thats how it was working for us and we checked the overall scheduled reminder select statements at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - made me go and double check that the Activity 'labelled' as 10 days prior actually was set up to be 10 days prior, and they are def. set for "10 days before Event Start Date". Also noting that these are Scheduled Reminders that are set up via the tab on the Event config screen not via the Communications > Scheduled Reminders but assume that should make no difference